# How to get a tag in JSON format+C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json format file like below with 10 items:

```
   "items": [
                {
                "kind": "Test#result",
                "cacheId": "PR1wQp1jFRQJ",
                 "pagemap": {
                    "person": [
                            {
                       "location": "Greater Minneapolis-St. Paul Area",
                       "role": "Test at Test"
                            }
                              ],
                   "metatags": [
                           {
                          "lnkd-track-json-lib": "test",
                           }
                               ],
                    "hcard": [
                          {
                   "title": "Wealth Advisor at XXX",
                   "photo": "contag.jpg"
                          },
                     {
                        "fn": "Unviersity of XXXX"
                     },
                   ]
               }
         },
         NEXT ITEM....
 ]
```

and I am using below code to get each item from this JSON:

```
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(String.Format("aurl.com?alt=json"));
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> collection = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,          object>>(result);
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> item in (IEnumerable)collection["items"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", item["kind"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Role: {0}", ??);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

How can I get "role" and location from this JSON using my logic?I use C# to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a class to represent your data and then using the serializer to create the class.

```
class items
{
    public string kind {get;set;}
    public string cacheId {get;set;}
    public string pagemap {get;set;}
    public person person {get;set;}

}

class person
{
    public string location {get;set;}
    public string role {get;set;}
}
```

and so on...

Then ...

```
string jsonInput="have your valid json input here"; //
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
items objItems  = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<items>(jsonInput)
```

we can now call our items as we would any other object in our class.

```
items.kind
items.cacheId
items.person.location
```

They key is laying the foundation for easier data access later.

Comment: so cant i use the object to get the role easily?

Comment: Yes, however if your data model is multiple objects just keep in mind that you must also show that in your classes.

so you may end up with `code`class Myclass { items[] items {get;set;}}`code`

Comment: Can you please update your code with multiple objects?

Comment: is it robust enough if there are other tags before items in the JSON? seems cant get all of items though...